# Module not found error , even after instaslling 2 times?

Tags: python-3.x

i installed einsteinpy using pip but when i run program it shows error
i also tried installing using conda , still no change

this is my code

```
import numpy as np
from einsteinpy.geodesic import Timelike
from einsteinpy.plotting import StaticGeodesicPlotter
position = [4, np.pi / 3, 0.]
momentum = [0., 0.767851, 2.]
a = 0.99
steps = 400.
delta = 0.5
```

the ERROR message is

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_12838/2788862847.py in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
      2 
----> 3 from einsteinpy.geodesic import Timelike
      4 from einsteinpy.plotting import StaticGeodesicPlotter

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'einsteinpy.geodesic'
```

I have installed `einsteinpy`, but I don't know why its still showing module not found.

Comment: How, precisely, did you install it? With `pip3 install einsteinpy`? `pip install einsteinpy`? Something else? Are you one Windows or Linux? Regardless, the usual answer is "never use `pip`/`pip3` to install", just do `python3 -mpip install einsteinpy` (on most Linux distros, where `python3` is whatever command you use to launch Python), or on Windows, with the Python launcher available, do `py -3 -mpip install einsteinpy` (and use `py -3` to launch Python as well). That said, it looks like your using Jupyter or the like, possibly through a web interface, which might be an unrelated Python.

Comment: sorry i left out so many details, i am using linux os , ubuntu 16 lts , i used pip install enisteinpy . Thanks for your advice i will try methods you suggested